# Do I need an array with Core Data?

Tags: ios, core-data, swift4

To delete, retrieve and count items, it seems I need an array to tag along with Core Data. TableView functions are a great example. You need to supply the `count` of items. The TableView provides `indexPath.row` for deleting and retrieving items.

Without an accompanying array that must be kept in sync with Core Data, how do you perform the above operations?

To accomplish this, I can abstract Core Data into a class and hide the array in the class with it.

Comment: `NSFetchedResultsController`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "To accomplish this, I can abstract Core Data into a class and hide the
>   array in the class with it"

I find it common and convenient to create a 'Data Coodinator' singleton in an application that uses the same data everywhere in the app, giving this singleton an array of your `NSManagedObject`'s is a powerful way of communicating dynamic data through many vc's without passing it via segue.

```
/**
**NSObject Singleton**

Coordinates data between CoreData, real-time database and ViewControllers.

- Eliminates the need to pass data from VC to VC.
- Reduces State Changes when manipulating user data
- Provides a common resource for scaling additional VC without passing data.
- Manages a single NSManagedObject by value
*/
final class DataCoordinator: NSObject {

private override init() {
    print("Data Coordinator Initialized")
}

static let sharedInstance = DataCoordinator()


var fetched: [YourNSManagedObjectModel] = []

//...
```

It's fairly common to have a "Database Controller" to preform your Core Data operations:

```
class DatabaseController {

private init() {

}

class func getContext () -> NSManagedObjectContext {
    return DatabaseController.persistentContainer.viewContext
}


static var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    //The container that holds both data model entities
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: <# NSManagedObjectClass #> )

    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

            /*
             Typical reasons for an error here include:
             * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
             * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
             * The device is out of space.
             * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
             Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
             */

            //TODO: - Add Error Handling for Core Data

            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
           }


         })
        return container
     }()

class func fetchAll () -> Array<YourNSManagedObjectModel> {
    let all = NSFetchRequest<YourNSManagedObjectModel>(entityName: "YourNSManagedObjectModel")

    var fetchedall:[YourNSManagedObjectModel] = []
    do {
        let fetched = try DatabaseController.getContext().fetch(all)
        fetchedall = fetched

    } catch {
        let nserror = error as NSError
        print(nserror.localizedDescription)
    }
    print("Fetched: \(fetchedall.count) Entites")

    return fetchedall
}
```

So you can set your DataCoodinator singleton fetched like:

```
DataCoordinator.sharedInstance.fetched = DatabaseController.fetchAll()
```

Then use fetched like a normal array in any vc.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return DataCoordinator.sharedInstance.fetched.count 
 }
```

once you are done updating/editing you can use simple function to save the Core Data context.

```
 DatabaseController.saveContext()


// MARK: - Core Data Saving support
class func saveContext() {
    let context = self.getContext()
    if context.hasChanges {
        do {
            try context.save()
            print("Data Saved to Context")
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. 
            //You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

And delete:

```
    DatabaseController.getContext().delete(fetched[index])
```

Comment: I think this is flawed. Your delete isn't going to update the fetched array. It is unaffected. Either way, you are also maintaining and array and Core Data and now it is out of sync.

Comment: You are deleting the item from the context, then update fetched the same way you set it with fetchAll()...

Comment: As for the out of sync, NSManagedObjects are pass by reference not value. They are the same objects as core data, not a duplicate.

Comment: When I run the above delete, the array still has the same number of items. Plus nothing is actually deleted from Core Data, which is probably a difference issue. Is the call to `delete()` all that is required is does something else need to run?

Comment: Delete the item from the context: `DatabaseController.getContext().delete(fetched[index])` then save the context: `DatabaseController.saveContext()` and finally  reset fetched: `DataCoordinator.sharedInstance.fetched = DatabaseController.fetchAll()`

Comment: On the `ManagedObjectContext`, I don't see a `saveContext()`. Did you mean `save()`, which is available?

Comment: ah- awesome! Thanks.

Comment: You may be able to help with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48066512/why-is-tableview-order-reversed-from-core-data-fetch-order. It's along the same lines.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need an array with Core Data?

**No.**

> TableView functions are a great example. You need to supply the `count` of items.

An array is only one of many possible countable collections of data.

> Without an accompanying array that must be kept in sync with Core Data, how do you perform the above operations?

You can use the managed object context. For example, there's a method called [`-\[NSManagedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:error:\]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506868-countforfetchrequest?language=objc) (or in Swift, [`count(for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506868-count)) that tells you how many instances of a given entity would be returned by the given fetch request. Or, more commonly, if you already have an object with a to-many relationship to the entity you're interested in, you can just access the property. For example, if you want to fill a table with the artists in your `recordCollection`, you might say something like `recordCollection.artists.count`.

You should definitely *not* try to keep a separate array in sync with your Core Data storage -- you'd be doing a lot of work to replicate the information that your Core Data store already contains, and trying to keep two separate sets of data in sync is always error prone.